# how to force a cucumber scenario to pass?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumberjs

I have my framework integrated with JIRA, wheneven I execute scripts, it will check with JIRA for the testcase status, then will it run. If it's already passed, right now I am handling it with

```
throw new SkipException("\"Scenario: \\\"\" + scenario.getName() + \"\\\" is already passed in the previous test cycle\"");
```

But this fails the scenario in reports.

Instead I want to show this scenario as PASS in the report. Any solution?

Comment: You are throwing an exception... I'm sure that's what causing it to fail. I'm assuming if you don't throw the exception, it would pass. I'm confused what the scenario is.

Comment: In cucumber, if you want to skip scenario based on certain requirements or logic we use skipException (testng) or assumeTrue method in junit. Problem is in cucumber it is failing the scenario. It is not the case if it is testng or junit tests

Comment: Cucumber also offers ways to skip scenarios (i.e. using tags) and there are ways to retry scenarios that have failed (I don't use those, so can't help there). If the reason you have to retry tests is that they are flaky, please consider fixing root causes of whatever makes them flaky.

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber JVM currently only recognizes [`org.junit.internal.AssumptionViolatedException` and `org.junit.AssumptionViolatedException`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/api/TestStep.java#L114) as skip exceptions. These can be thrown through Junit [Assume](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html).

I assume you're using TestNG to throw the `SkipException`. This exception is not supported. You'll have to create a PR to get it supported.

Comment: By Using the `Assert.assume()`, thrown exception is printed to log, can i avoid it ? i want to keep logs clean

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose [there is built-in support for skipping scenario](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/step_definitions.md#skipped-steps)

just return `skipped` string from your step.

As result it will be in special "Skipped" state which should be marked as OK in most of the reporting frameworks (usually gray color).

Comment: Your awnsers applies to cucumber *js* not *jvm*.